# Java Generic Tree Traversal

Tags: java, tree, traversal

I have a problem to solve in Java. I have a tree that needs to be traversed. Here it is:

```
        1
     /     \
   1 2 3  1 2 3      
 /   |  \    \
123 123 123  same for those three nodes
```

Now the way it needs to be traversed is starting from the root and going do the deepest leftmost node (here 1) and its leftmost leaf (1). After that it should begin again from the root tracing all the numbers and this time reach the next leaf of the same deepest leftmost node .. and so on, that is begin from the top, each time reaching one by one all the remaining leafs of that node. After all the leafs of the leftmost node have been traced than it should proceed as usual (starting from the top) and now moving to the next uninvited node (here 2) .. and so on for all the tree. So the first 6 traces would be:

111
112
113
121
122
123 
... and so on

All of the traced numbers need to be traced and recorded in order, the way described above. Anyone can help out with algorithm on how to achieve it?. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a tree-traversal algorithm.

```
void traverse(Node root, String path) {
    path += root.getValue();
    for (Node child : root.getChildren())
        traverse(child, path);

    // end of current traversal
    if (root.getChildren().isEmpty())
        System.out.print(path + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is known as [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). You should know that this is not the most efficient algorthim for the job, there are better ones such as [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Depending on what you're trying to do there are even more specialised tactics which can be employed such as [Alpha-Beta Pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning) or other heuristics for game playing searches.

If you're set on using Depth First Search and wish to return a path from the root to that node you could use something like the following once you've found your goal node. Assuming `node` is your goal node...

```
List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
path.add(node);
while(node.parent != null){
  path.add(node.parent);
  node = node.parent;
}
return path; //returns a path from {goal,...,root}
```

Comment: @unbeli Yes, you're right ..it's god nothing to do with search .. so far though no ideas from anyone on how to do it ..